# Save Logged in state for appropriate user in IOS and Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using only one login screen for different users on the app I'm developing and I added a code to save the logged in user so that the user doesn't have to log in again next time they open the app. But the fact that I have different users, I'm only able to send the user to one segue.

I've tried adding the code to keep the user logged in, but if I login with another user it sends the user to the same view controller as before. Here's what I tried:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
            // User is signed in.
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "studentSegue", sender: self)
        } else {
            // No user is signed in.
            return
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to keep the user logged in for different users, but I'm not sure what code to use. To differentiate the users on the login page I used switch case to find the user "Type" and log in on that. But I want to keep the appropriate user logged in. Any help would be much appreciated

EDIT: What am trying to say is if two people on different phones try to login lets say student (phone A) and teacher (phone B) they should just log in once and not have to log in again when they close the app. But my login "PerformSegue" only lets me show the "studentSegue"

Comment: you can save the state for the type of user and then use the SegueIdentifier of that type.

Comment: How do i save the state of the current user? And how to add different SegueIdentifier?

Comment: To save the user look into `UserDefaults` , And add another more Segue as per your need. Or update your question to get an exact response to clearly stated problem

Comment: How should i update my question? I also tried using UserDefaults to save the current user but that as well didn't work. Maybe i didn't do it properly

Comment: Just save bool value in UserDefaults once user login for first time in application, and when user open application again, fetch that UserDefaults value and check bool if bool if true , don't show login page again.

Comment: Firebase Authentication has only a single actively signed in user, which you can access through `Auth.auth().currentUser`, and which is automatically persisted between app restarts. You don't need to write any code to enable that. If you want to respond to changes in the sign-in state, use an auth state listener as shown in the first snippet under this link: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user

Comment: The logic here is a bit challenging; The question states you have one login screen and multiple users. But then you want to save the user so they don't have to log in again. That would mean if a user logs in then quits and re-opens the app, they will automatically log in again, which would not give another user the chance to log in?? What does *I'm trying to keep the user logged in for different users* mean - how can a user be logged in for different users? If you can clarify the logic in the question, we may be able to present a solution.

Comment: @Jay I've updated my question. What i'm trying to say is if two users on different phone try to log in, they should log in just once until they log out. Hope that makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying quite a lot i managed to find the answer myself. So what i did was set an integer with `UserDefaults.standard.set(1, forKey: "isLoggedIn")` each time a user would log in. I set number 1 for student and number 2 for teacher and in viewDidAppear i did this:

```swift
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        if UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "isLoggedIn") == 1 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "studentSegue", sender: self)
        }

        if UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: "isLoggedIn") == 2 {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "lecturerSegue", sender: self)
        }

        else{
            return
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me restate the question

*On my app, I have two different types of users, student and teacher. When a student logs in or restarts the app, it should take them to the student section via a segue. When a teacher logs in or restarts the app, it should take them to a teacher section via a segue.*

A few things

Firebase doesn't have user types, only users - to Firebase, every user is the same as every other user. Your app code and structure determine the difference.

One solution is to ask Firebase what kind of user it is upon app start. here's some generic code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
        let uid = currentUser.uid
        let thisUserRef = fbRoot.child("users").child(uid)
        thisUserRef.observeSingleEvent(..... {
           let userType = //get userType from snapshot
           if userType == "student" {
              performSegue(withIdentifier: "studentSegue", sender: self)
           } else {
              performSegue(withIdentifier: "teacherSegue", sender: self)
           }
        }

    } else {
        // No user is signed in.
        return
    }
}
```

Another option is to store the userType in the userDefaults. So if the user is auth'd, get the user type from the defaults and perform the appropriate segue. I am not a huge fan of this approach due to security but it can work.

Comment: How do i get userType from Snapshot? I was using a switch, case code for the login, should i use the same?

Comment: @Javy14 You would get a value from a snapshot as you would get any value from a snapshot. Are you familiar with Firebase and how to read and write data? Using a switch or an IF statement is up to you... its really a coding style preference.

Comment: Yeah i am a bit but i'm getting error while getting the snapshot.

Comment: @Javy14 Very good. If you are not familiar with Firebase, the Firebase Getting Started guide [Read and Write Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write) is a great place to start. If you are familiar with it, and you're having difficulty with a piece of code, post a separate question that includes the code, your Firebase structure (as text) and a description of the issue and we will take a look!

Comment: I don't think the code you suggested works. I've been trying for quite a while now

Comment: @Javy14 It works perfectly! I pulled it from a production app. It is pretty generic so you will need to set it up for your environment. For example, we have a class var called fbRoot that allows us to use that one var to communicate with Firebase. You may have something different. Likewise, your Firebase structure may be different than ours so your node is called userType, and ours is called userClass. You have student and teacher and we have public, standard_user and admin_user. You'll need to change it around to fit your use case, but I assure you that it works.